# Text animation run when in viewport in Wordpress with Elementor

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, viewport, elementor

I'm having some problems running the code only when in viewport.

I have a Wordpress website with Elementor and I'm trying to have the text animation run only when in viewport, but it always runs on the page load and the animation is finished by the time i get to the section with the text.

HTML

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:400,500,600" rel="stylesheet">

<svg viewBox="0 0 400 70">
  <symbol id="text-copy">
    <text text-anchor="middle" x="50%" y="80%" class="text--line">DESPRE NOI</text>
  </symbol>
  <g class="g-ants">
    <use xlink:href="#text-copy"
      class="text-copy" id="outline"></use>
    <use xlink:href="#text-copy"
      class="text-copy" id="fill"></use> 
  </g>
</svg>
```

CSS

```
svg {
  width:100%;
}
.text--line {
  font-size:4rem;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-weight:600;
}

#outline {
  fill: none;
  stroke:#406663;
  stroke-dasharray:100%;
  stroke-dashoffset:0;
  animation-name: outline;
  animation-duration: 4.5s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

#fill {
  fill-opacity: 0;
  fill:#406663;
  animation-name: fill;
  animation-duration: 3.5s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}


@-webkit-keyframes outline{
  from{
    stroke-dashoffset:100%;
  }
  
  to{
    stroke-dashoffset:0;
  }
}

@keyframes fill{
  from{
    fill-opacity: 0;
  }
  
  to{
    fill-opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

I searched some things on Google, but i don't seem to find something that works or i don't know how to implement it.